# malloc on Windows

Tags: c, windows, malloc

I'm new in this forum and i hope to do it right. 
My problem is the following:
 I'm writing a program that has this function:

```
void* s_malloc(int _size, int dim){
    printf("%d %d\n", _size, dim);
    char* pointer;
    pointer = (char*)malloc(_size * dim);
    printf("Malloc eseguita \n");
    if(pointer == NULL){
        ExitFailure(strerror(errno));
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < dim * _size; i++){
            pointer[i] = '\0';
        }
        printf("Allocata\n");
        return (void*)pointer;
    }
    return (void*) NULL;
}
```

I tested this function a lot ( In the truth i wrote this function a month ago and since that moment i have used it a lot ). I'm pretty sure that the function works fine. 
However in this other function i use 's_malloc' and it crash

```
#define LDTOCAT "C:\\Users\\admin\\logdrstrace\\"

void startProcess(){
    char* logfile, *logfilefullpath;
    int run = TRUE, lenth = 0;

    /*
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i ++){
        s_malloc(60, 1);
    }*/ commented

    while(run){
        logfile = checkLogFileDirectory();
        Sleep(1000);
        #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
        printf("\nValue returned: %s\n", logfile);
        fflush(stdout);
        #endif // DEBUG_MODE
        if(strcmp(logfile, NOFILEFOUND) != 0){
            run = FALSE;
        }
    }
    lenth = (strlen(LDTOCAT)+strlen(logfile)+1);
     #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
        printf("Let's go forward allocating memory: size %d\n", lenth);
        printf("LDTOCAT size: %d, logfile size: %d + 1\n", strlen(LDTOCAT), strlen(logfile));
        fflush(stdout);
        #endif // DEBUG_MODE

    logfilefullpath =(char*) s_malloc(lenth, sizeof(char));
    #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    printf("Memory created!\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    #endif // DEBUG_MODE
    memcpy(logfilefullpath, LDTOCAT, sizeof(LDTOCAT));
    #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    printf("Created logfilefullpath with directory: %s\n", logfilefullpath);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("File found: %s\n", strcat(logfilefullpath, logfile));
    #endif // DEBUG_MODE

    int fd = open(strcat(LDTOCAT, logfile), O_RDONLY);
    if(fd <= OK){
        ExitFailure(strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a for loop at the begginning commented. Now we have three possibility:
1) If i compile and run the program it fails in s_malloc function when it executes the command 'loginfulpath = (char*)s_malloc(lenth, sizeof(char))' it enters in s_malloc and crash when it calls the original malloc. Sometimes the errno varible is setted on "Not enough memory" but sometimes crashes and stop. 
2) if i decomment the loop at the begginning and the stop condition is 'i<15' it crashes like in the point one
3)if i put the stop condition 'i<16', magically, it works fine.

there is a third function that opens a directory and looks for a file,
infact as you can see in the code it avoids the first 2 files found becouse
they are . and ..

```
#define NOFILEFOUND "Nothing"

 char* checkLogFileDirectory(){
 HANDLE hfile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
 WIN32_FIND_DATA fdata, nullValue;
 char* file = NULL;
 int counter=0;
 while(hfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
 hfile = FindFirstFileA(LOGDIR, &nullValue);
 }
 #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
 printf("-FileFound: %s\n", nullValue.cFileName);
#endif // DEBUG_MODE
 while(FindNextFile(hfile, &fdata) && counter != 2){
        #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
        printf("-File found: %s\n", fdata.cFileName);
        #endif // DEBUG_MODE
    if(counter == 1){
         #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
        printf("Third file it's my file\n");
        #endif // DEBUG_MODE
        file = s_malloc(strlen(fdata.cFileName), sizeof(char));
        memcpy(file, fdata.cFileName, strlen(fdata.cFileName)+1);
        if(file == NULL){
            ExitFailure("Error reading file");
        }
        file[strlen(fdata.cFileName)] = '\0';

    }
    counter ++;
 }
 #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
 printf("\n\=>File selected: %s", file==NULL | file == "" ? NOFILEFOUND:file);
 #endif // DEBUG_MODE
 return counter == 2? file : NOFILEFOUND;
}
```

NB: I printed the vaule of any varibles and they were correct, 
I'm on Virtual machine with vmware workstation.
I'm sorry for my english i hope you will able to understand it

This is the output when it crashes in cases 1 or 2

```
-FileFound: .
-File found: ..
-File found: drstrace.calc.exe.00532.0000.log
Third file it's my file
32 1
Malloc eseguita
Allocata

=>File selected: drstrace.calc.exe.00532.0000.log
Value returned: drstrace.calc.exe.00532.0000.log
Let's go forward allocating memory: size 60
LDTOCAT size: 27, logfile size: 32 + 1
60 1
Malloc eseguita
Error: Not enough space!!
```

Thank you!!

Comment: IMO the problem is `strcat` that appends something to string literal.

Comment: thank you for the fast answer but the problem is different, If i did it right when memory is created in s_malloc it is initilised and filled with '\0'. And the lenth i give to the function in the nedded plus 1. So the string has '\0' in the last byte. Thank you anyway

Comment: yeah `open(strcat(LDTOCAT, logfile), O_RDONLY)` is wrong if `LDTOCAT` is a string literal. My answer is probably wrong. Deleting it.

Comment: Anyway the problem is before strcat ,

Comment: `printf("File found: %s\n", strcat(logfilefullpath, logfile));` this is also strange. Why not doing `printf("File found: %s%s\n", logfilefullpath, logfile);` and avoid a risky `strcat`

Comment: #define LDTOCAT "C:\\Users\\admin\\logdrstrace\\". Ok this is the declaretion of LDTOCAT.

Comment: can we see the execution traces (right before it crashes) to see the sizes printed.

Comment: are you sure `checkLogFileDirectory();` returns a valid string? can we see the code of this?

Comment: the size printed are 60 and 1

Comment: It is just a mistake to assume that the memory corruption occurred in this snippet.  It could have happened *anywhere* in code that ran before this.   Get rid of s_malloc and replace with calloc() so you can use standard heap corruption diagnostic tooling like crtdbg.h and Application Verifier.

Comment: @HansPassant you say that the corruption of heap could be before that calling? Ok i'll try to look for mistake in that direction

Comment: @Valgio now that you posted the new snippet, I have found a serious issue, check my edited answer.

Comment: @HansPassant `file = s_malloc(strlen(fdata.cFileName), sizeof(char));
memcpy(file, fdata.cFileName, strlen(fdata.cFileName)+1);` That is _wrong_ for sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your allocation function is okay (it's a poor man's version of `calloc` with error checking, maybe using `calloc` would save some manual code and would be more efficient)

But in `checkLogFileDirectory` this code is wrong:

```
file = s_malloc(strlen(fdata.cFileName), sizeof(char));
memcpy(file, fdata.cFileName, strlen(fdata.cFileName)+1);
```

there's not enough space for `file` (nul-terminating char). You're missing 1 byte, which can corrupt the rest of your application by undefined behaviour (allocating 15 or 16 useless blocks sometimes makes it "work" because it changes the memory layout).

Why not just do:

```
file = strdup(fdata.cFileName);
```

Also, as noted in comments, if you reach a further point of your program you'll have a big issue here:

```
int fd = open(strcat(LDTOCAT, logfile), O_RDONLY);
```

`LDTOCAT` is a *string literal*, you cannot apply `strcat` on it. And even if you could, you wouldn't have enough room.

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll correct it now! For the open() yes, this is another error but i have never reached this point ahahha

Comment: Oh yes!! for now it works good! Thank you very much! Too much kind :)

Answer (score 1):

```
HANDLE hfile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
WIN32_FIND_DATA fdata, nullValue;
while(hfile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    hfile = FindFirstFileA(LOGDIR, &nullValue);
}
```

Note that this loop will run forever if something is wrong. Then you put the whole function in another `while` loop.

If the function call is valid then you have success the first time, otherwise you cannot fix a problem with brute force.

You are not closing `hfile`. You have many more errors in this section. There are plenty of examples and documentation for `FindFirstFile` you can consult.

You already have `strcat`, you should have `strcpy` too. `strcpy` will add null terminator at the end of the string. Just use the standard `malloc` and `strcpy`

You have to `free` the `malloc` allocation, so it's simpler if your function always returns a pointer and `NULL` on failure.

```
char* checkLogFileDirectory()
{
    char* file = NULL;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fdata;
    HANDLE hfile = FindFirstFile("C:\\Users\\admin\\logdrstrace\\*.log", &fdata);
    if(hfile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do 
        {
            if(strcmp(fdata.cFileName, ".") == 0 || strcmp(fdata.cFileName, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            int len = strlen(fdata.cFileName);
            file = malloc(len + 1);
            strcpy(file, fdata.cFileName);
            break;
        } while(FindNextFile(hfile, &fdata));
        FindClose(hfile);
    }
    return file;
}

int main()
{
    char *file = checkLogFileDirectory();
    if(file) {
        printf("%s\n", file);
        free(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok! I'll make this change. Tahnk you very much

Comment: Yes! I modified my program as you said! Thank, it's more readable, and correct

Comment: Good. By the way, you don't have to worry about malloc failing to allocate 200 or 300 bytes. Unless you are running your program on a device with severe memory limitation!